# BSOD Kernel Mode Heap Corruption after failure to display

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, minidumps

I attempted to turn on my PC from hibernate and the display would not turn on, which has happened once before a few weeks ago. I was forced to hard reboot, and it ran with no problems for a few hours. It then crashed to blue screen and gave me kernel mode heap corruption error. I was only running Chrome and Firefox, uploading some files and reading an article, no gaming. I have used memory diagnostic and sfc /scannow, but I'm having trouble parsing the error logs. From what I understand in WinDbg it is "0x11 : The heap detected invalid internal state during the current operation. This is usually the result of a buffer overflow.", but I don't know where to go from here. Is it the new Nvidia driver, possibly? I do not have the option to roll it back in Device Manager. Here are the minidump files:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DS2dcPiYk8UrkWAjwYg-ad_j2sbyO3BU/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ta4M5JdBIcz88OcI7mpaYzK0ViRhTwkU/view?usp=sharing

Update: my PC crashed once again and I got a dpc watchdog violation.

Update 2: I rolled back the Nvidia driver and it worked for about 6 hours, then crashed with a kernel security check failure. I have no clue what else could be causing the problem. I wasn't running any games, I was just browsing on Chrome and uploading a file on Firefox.

Comment: Yes, SFC logs are *huge*, and I also take on faith the operation fixed what it could. You might also use  Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM), https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image , for further repairs. Since Hibernate uses the drive to store system state, you might also check the SSD or HDD free space and S.M.A.R.T. stats for issues.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik my SSD has 35 gb free, and 223 gb on my HDD. sfc repaired what it found, though I'm not sure that was the cause.  SMART returned OK on wmic, and I ran a few DISM operations as well. No corruptions were found, likely from sfc.